Problems with the telegram chatbot. The chat was not found, although it is there
Bot is the first bot to communicate with the mailing management, and botspam is the bot in which the mailing takes place.
def step5(message):
    global p
    conn = sqlite3.connect('../chatgpt_database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT tid FROM Users")
    massive_big = cursor.fetchall()
    sss = [   ]
    sss = []
    for photo in photos:
        if '.jpg' in photo:
            sss.append(telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open(photo, 'rb'), caption=txt))
        else:
            sss.append(telebot.types.InputMediaVideo(open(photo, 'rb'), caption=txt))
    for z in range(len(massive_big)):
        # try:
            if not p: 
                botspam.send_message(int(massive_big[z][0]), txt)
            else:
                botspam.send_media_group(int(massive_big[z][0]), sss)
        # except:
        #     print(-1)
    p = True
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправка окончена, для новой рассылки нажми /start")

The error is this:
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found

The error are reflected in these lines:
if not p: 
    botspam.send_message(int(massive_big[z][0]), txt)
else:
    botspam.send_media_group(int(massive_big[z][0]), sss)

